# How to test an API service in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, api

How can I use the debug a service within Visual Studio 2010?  What I would like to do is step thru the code as the request is being processed.

I am running the service by right clicking on the web site project (C:...\APIServiceSite) within the solution and selecting "View in Browser".  Everything runs OK and I get the expected results back from the service but I cannot find a way to step thru the code which is in a another project (APIService) within the same solution.

Comment: We need more information.  Have you tried to place break points within this other project?  There are other ways to debug a service like this which do not involve using Visual Studio.

Comment: What other info do you need?  I have tried to debug this project like I would any other project, by putting a break point at the area of concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head: Right click the service project and choose Debug >> Start New Instance. Then start the debug on your web "test" application. You should now be able to accomplish what you desire. (since this is off the top of my head, if it fails, it is very close to the right answer).

A better option is to move the functionality into a class library and make the web service project very thin (essentially returning calls from the class library assembly). You can then test the business functionality by using a unit test library, like MSTest (built in with most team system SKUs of Visual Studio) or nUnit (etc). Sure the tests will likely be integration tests, but you accomplish two good things:

1. You get the UI out of the testing equation so you can focus on the business logic
2. You create repeatable tests (think science, not art)

I find it a really bad pattern to have moving parts in a UI project, unless the moving parts are focused on presentation of data. And, yes, I see web services as a UI, even though the user is an application rather than a human body.

Comment: Yes, it did.  I had a *doh!* moment.  You just showed me I can unit test my web services/WCF apps without the overhead of IIS.  Thanks!

Comment: @Wesley: Yes, the developer web server (with WCF, you can also head to using a transport other than HTTP). And, if you need IIS, but don't need the entire IIS, there are the new lighter bits that Hanselman, et al, talk about.

Answer (score 0):

I debug a service by making a standard wpf application that uses it. By adding Existing item / Add as link all source file from the service into a new project (wpf application), into a separate folder of this application. So i can test it, and debug the same way i test/debug an application.
Note that you might use the microsoft log service to log issues that your service may have when running as a service. For handling the errors, i made one MustOverload (in vb) function that handle errors, and i overload it as a MessageBox when using the service in my test app, and overload it as ms log when it runs as service

(quick info on log here :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984385(v=VS.71).aspx
 )